# Plotting Your CPU Temperature in Real Time

Tags: monitoring

On Linux systems, the `sensors` command shows information about your system's temperature:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +63.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +64.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.90 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.00 V)
temp1:        +42.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
```

Are there well-known Mathematica paclets or techniques that one can use to track system temperature in real-time (especially CPU/core temperatures)?

Comment: Mathematica does not provide this functionality built in. You'd likely have to hook up to some third party tool.

Answer (score 5):

Install the `sensors` command by using `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

Given the output on my system, a little string manipulation gives the temperature of each of the six cores.

```
temp[]:=
   Block[{s,p},
      s=RunProcess["sensors","StandardOutput"];
      p=Drop[StringPosition[s,":"],2][[All,1]];
      Map[ToExpression[StringTake[s,{#+11,#+14}]]&,p]
]
```

Now run within `Dynamic`

```
Dynamic[
   ListLinePlot[temp[],
      InterpolationOrder->0,Filling->Axis,
      PlotRange->{{1,6},{15,30}},
      Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"Core Number","Temperature  C"}]
]
```

[image: dynamic temperatures]

Comment: Your answer is great. I want to know how to get CPU temperature information under the Windows system.